# How can i compare and seach string and datetime c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, datetime

i create a simple searching with compare string like :

```
articles = _service.ArticleRepository.GetAll(id, new Expression<Func<Article, bool>>[] { x => x.Title.Contains(searchWord) }, a => a.ArticleCategory);
```

And Works fine; but i want search in datetime(date) , I wrote different codes:

```
articles = _service.ArticleRepository.GetAll(id, new Expression<Func<Article, bool>>[] { x => x.InsertDate ==DateTime.Parse(searchWord) }, a => a.ArticleCategory);
```

or

```
articles = _service.ArticleRepository.GetAll(id, new Expression<Func<Article, bool>>[] { x => x.InsertDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd").Contains(searchWord) }, a => a.ArticleCategory);
```

Give me an error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime
>   Parse(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated
>   into a store expression.
>
> From this line          int count = _db.Count();

How can I do something comparing between string and date by entering a date as a string (in different formats like: 2017/8/5 or 05/05/2017 or 2017-8-5 or ...) or even entering a number(Search all dates that have a number)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a LINQ query gets executed, it will get converted to the equivalent SQL statement. `DateTime.Parse` is a C# method which converts a string to it's corresponding DateTime. There is no corresponding SQL equivalant to do so.

You need to create a DateTime object before your LINQ query and use that.

```
var d = DateTime.Parse(searchWord);
var result= someEntityCollection.Where(a =>a.CreatedTime==d));
```

If `CreatedTime` is a `DateTime` field, the comparison **will include the time stamp as well**. That means, it will not simply give records for that date, but that date and that specific time part

If you are trying to filter records for a specific date (**Without time**) ,you may use the `DbFunctions.TruncateTime` helper method to do so

```
var d = DateTime.Parse(searchWord);
var result= someEntityCollection.Where(a => 
          DbFunctions.TruncateTime(a.CreatedTime)== DbFunctions.TruncateTime(d.Date))
```

The   `DbFunctions.TruncateTime`  helper method is defined inside `System.Data.Entity` namespace. So make sure you have a using statement to use that.

```
using System.Data.Entity;
```

Also It is safe to use `DateTime.ParseExact` or `TryParseExact` with the format, than using `DateTime.Parse`

```
var d = DateTime.ParseExact(searchWord, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the conversion outside of your query:

```
var date=DateTime.Parse(searchWord);
articles = _service.ArticleRepository.GetAll(id, new Expression<Func<Article, bool>>[] { x => x.InsertDate ==date }, a => a.ArticleCategory);
```